# What's the best way to make two dimensional array from string[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm trying to read lines from txt file like this:

```
string[] data = File.ReadAllLines("data.txt");
```

What i need to make is char[,] array, which dimensions are:

```
[single row from txt file chars count] X [row from txt file count].
```

Then this char array have to be filled with data from string[] data.

Is there any easy way to do this ? I'm trying to convert string to char somehow but I can't. Any ideas?

Comment: `char[,]` does not make sense. you should use jagged array. `char[][]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`ToCharArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx) on each line.

```
String filepath = @"C:\test.txt";
Char[][] result = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).Select(obj => obj.ToCharArray()).ToArray();
```

It's worth noting that this will give you a `Char[][]` (which is a [jagged array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) ), and **not** `Char[,]` (which is a [multidimensional array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx))

Comment: That's great. But how can I display 'result' in richTextBox ?

Comment: @infexo37 how you want to display result in richtextbox

Comment: @infexo37: all you asked for in the original question was how to generate the 2D array. If you have more requirements, ask another question or elaborate your original question, please.

Comment: @code4life is right; if your question has changed, you'd need to ask another (separate) question.  However, I would advise *against* changing the question to include this new requirement.